# Hiding using VPN

Tags: network, vpn, cisco

I have just connected to a vpn server in my University using Cisco AnyConnect.

But when I check http://whatismyipaddress.com/, it still says that I'm in the same country as before I connected to the vpn server in some other country.

The IP address does not change in the visited page when I activate the VPN, and reload it.

I don't see any errors from my VPN client. The ip address doesn't change even though I connect to the VPN. The VPN I use is issued by my university. In Statistics, it says `Tunnel Mode (IPv4): Split Include and Tunnel Mode (IPv6): Drop All Traffic`

Should I do some additional steps to hide?

Comment: Does your IP change when you enable the VPN? If not you probably have it misconfigured.

Comment: No it doesn't change

Comment: Because it is a split configuration by design. Whoever is reading this, the question is very pertinent for this student, and for others in the same situation, this setting provides a false sense of security, please peruse my answer. As usual, it is not enough using the tools, but is crucial understanding what they are doing.

Comment: @Jamgreen I expanded the post with a free solution for you. I also edited your post, waiting it to be approved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide your GPS info. My browser asked me permission to use GPS location services in my Macbook Pro when I was entering the whatismyipaddress URL that you are visiting, and I denied it. So the site is asking for that.

So it believes I am in California, USA. Otherwise with GPS, the scripts/site would find out my true location.

It could be also that your VPN is configured for split tunnelling, and only used for accessing corporate resources; and hence all the Internet traffic going the usual route (outside the VPN). Not that usual, but it is a possibility.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling

To check it out wether you have split tunnelling or no, is fairly easy, the IP on whatismyipaddress has to change once you activate the VPN service and reload the page.

As @Neil points out, it could also be the VPN not working, however usually in that case the Cisco software normally throws a very visible error.

I actually went at the end of this conversation with @Neil to settings->security->privacy in my "El Capitan" and took out location services permission for good from Safari.

Conclusion: From the dialogue with the OP, it is indeed confirmed the VPN service is configured as Split mode only for providing services for specific services/networks in the University.

That configuration, confirmed by `Tunnel Mode (IPv4): Split Include`, while not frequent (or correctly forbidden) in corporate setups, is often done for students, for them to not abuse the VPN/academic infra-structure, namely using p2p services from home to avoid consequences.

In this case, the only route is to find an alternative VPN service, possibly a commercial one. I actually use VPN unlimited, there are others.

Or using Tor+onion browser. https://www.torproject.org

Comment: This is one possibility but perhaps not the OP's actual problem.

Comment: Perhaps the VPN isn't properly configured and running?

Comment: it can be something else...I will add to the post. I am supposing the OP is wise enough to read the VPN throwing errors obviously.

Comment: Do you know if http://whatismyipaddress.com/ uses scripts or other GPS-enabled functionality? I thought that site was a straight reverse IP lookup.

Comment: I have privacy settings here, and it asked me confirmation to use GPS...only happens when the site asks for it.

Comment: I actually went now to settings->security->privacy and took out GPS from good for Safari.

Comment: That looks much better. Presumably you're on a mobile? You may want to add that to your answer.

Comment: Read it better "my Mac"...I will improve that anyway.

Comment: I have a few VPN services here...good for testing. Even to access remotely my network at home, I have a VPN.

Comment: I don't see any errors from my VPN client. The ip address doesn't change even though i connect to the VPN. The VPN I use is issued by my university. In Statistics, it says `Tunnel Mode (IPv4): Split Include` and `Tunnel Mode (IPv6): Drop All Traffic`

Comment: check routes before and after VPN. My guess is that they are only giving you routes for their networks, and not a default route for all traffic. We also have that problem at our faculty, students tend to abuse the VPN for "free VPN services" and for bittorrent

Comment: Is is confirmed then, split mode. The VPN is not supposed to give you routes for the Internet at large, but only for specific networks in the faculty.

Comment: Oh okay. But it does allow me to see some websites which were blocked before connecting

Comment: Nope. All the Internet connection still goes via the usual route, the VPN only allows you to access University services by design. (i.e. it is intentional)

Comment: About the mobile comment: nowadays most of the browsers in the desktop, derive the geolocation from your "real" ip. To fool them you will have to do vpn at your router level